# Legal issue with open source font?

Tags: internet, open-source-software

I use a free, open source font called "Metropolis" for my webpages.

However, apparently there now is a legal issue due to similarities to a licensed font called "Gotham", owned by Hoefler&Co.

See https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/metropolis-font-repo-missing/69415 for more infos. The author Chris Simpson had to put his Github repo to private.

I wondered if there now are any legal consequences for new and old projects which actively use this font. I actually still see it in use of many big players too, i.e. https://www.vmware.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

### If Metropolis is an infringing copy of Gotham you have no right to use it

In effect, you are using Gotham and you don’t have a licence to do so. You can be sued.